# Text box not changes for default drop down value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `txtSubTotal` text box, a `discount` drop down and a `txtGrossTotal` text box. `txtSubTotal` text box is updating when the `ADD` button is clicked. `txtGrossTotal` text box is updating when the drop down value is selected. But, when updating the `txtSubTotal` text box, at the same time `txtGrossTotal` text box should be updated for the default drop down value, which is "0". Here, `txtGrossTotal` should be the value of `txtSubTotal`.

Below is my code, it doesn't display the `txtGrossTotal` when the drop down has it's default value. (But, after selecting another option, and again select the default value, it updates the `txtGrossTotal`.)

```
function discountedGrossTotal(dropdownVal){
var discountOption = document.getElementById("discount"),
subTotal = document.getElementById("txtSubTotal"),
grossTotal = document.getElementById("txtGrossTotal").value;

grossTotal.value = subTotal.value - (subTotal.value * dropdownVal/100);}
```

**`discount` drop down**

```
<select class="select" id="discount" name="discount" onchange="discountedGrossTotal(this.value);">
<option selected>0</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

**`txtGrossTotal` HTML**

```
 <div id="gross_total_div">
 <input name="txtGrossTotal" type="text" id="txtGrossTotal" size="15" readonly/>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Edit your question, and show when/how you are calling the `discountedGrossTotal` function. It is likely that you have not set it as selection events for the fields

Comment: It seems like you are calling discountedGrossTotal() when dropdown value is changed. Call this method even when you  enter value to txtSubTotal

Comment: @Bonatti I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to take the same action by changing the "discount" dropdown value as well as the "subtotal" textbox value. So, you will have to call the same function on both.

You can achieve this by doing below modifications in your code:

1. Remove the parameters from "discountedGrossTotal" function
2. Add a new variable inside your function like dropdownVal = document.getElementById("discount").value
3. Call the same function on change event of your "txtSubTotal" textbox

Now, this function will be called if any of these (textbox or dropdown) value is changed and hence the "Gross Total" value will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this, it should work for you...

```js
        function discountedGrossTotal() {
            var dropdownVal= document.getElementById("discount").options[document.getElementById("discount").selectedIndex].innerHTML;
            subTotal = document.getElementById("txtSubTotal");
            grossTotal = document.getElementById("txtGrossTotal").value;
            document.getElementById("txtGrossTotal").value = subTotal.value - (subTotal.value * dropdownVal / 100);
        }
```

```html
  sub total:   <input type="text" id="txtSubTotal" onblur="discountedGrossTotal()" />
    <br />

    discount:  <select class="select" id="discount" name="discount" onchange="discountedGrossTotal();">
        <option selected>0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <div id="gross_total_div">
        <input name="txtGrossTotal" type="text" id="txtGrossTotal" size="15" readonly />
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, bored of editing all your post, hopefully you get the jist now. Please format your answers correctly.